# design pattern to avoid unnecessary addition of abstract functions to accommodate new functionality

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

In below code I have abstract class `TestAlgModule` which I will be exposing to library users and there are several functionalities they can use such as `VOLUME, MIXER` and so on. However, suppose users need a new function which is added only in `MixerManager` then I need to add that in `TestAlgModule` abstract class and now suddenly all the derived class needs to add that without any benefit.

How do I avoid this?

```
 #include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                        
 using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                       

 enum {VOLUME, MIXER, UNKNONWN};                                                                                                                                                                            

 class TestAlgModule {                                                                                                                                                                                      
 public:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     virtual void open(int type) = 0;                                                                                                                                                                       
     virtual void close(int type) = 0;                                                                                                                                                                      
 };                                                                                                                                                                                                         

 class volumeManager : public TestAlgModule                                                                                                                                                                 
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 public:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     void open(int type) {}                                                                                                                                                                                 
     void close(int type) {}                                                                                                                                                                                
 };                                                                                                                                                                                                         

 class mixerManager : public TestAlgModule                                                                                                                                                                  
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 public:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     void open(int type) {}                                                                                                                                                                                 
     void close(int type) {}                                                                                                                                                                                
     void differentFunction() {};                                                                                                                                                                           
 };                                                                                                                                                                                                         

 /* users calls this to get algModule and then call functions to get the job done */                                                                                                                                                                                         
 TestAlgModule *getTestAlgModule(int type) {                                                                                                                                                                
     switch(type) {                                                                                                                                                                                         
         case VOLUME:                                                                                                                                                                                       
             return new volumeManager();                                                                                                                                                                    
         case MIXER:                                                                                                                                                                                        
             return new mixerManager();                                                                                                                                                                     
         default:                                                                                                                                                                                           
             break;                                                                                                                                                                                         
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     return nullptr;                                                                                                                                                                                        
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                               
     TestAlgModule * test = getTestAlgModule(MIXER);                                                                                                                                         
     test->open();     
     //test->differentFunction();          this can't be called as it is not part of abstract class and users are exposed only abstract class                                                                                                                                                              
     return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                              
 }
```

If something is not clear please let me know and I will do my best to answer it. I am looking for a better way to do this i.e. change in `VolumeManager` should be independent of `MixerManager`.

Comment: Why would you add the new function to `TestAlgModule` when it is already provided by `MixerManager`?

Comment: @JaMiT I don't want to add, but ```MixerManager``` is having this new function which is not part of ```TestAlgModule``` so user can't call it so in order for user to call it I need to add it as part of ```TestAlgModule``` and now ```VolumeManager``` needs to also add it.

Comment: Why doesn't the user just use `new mixerManager()`, `new volumeManager()`, etc, to get the thing he wants?

Comment: @MattTimmermans:  because I want to have a common interface for the library and algorithms are not exposed to the user. However if a new algorithm comes into being and it has a function which I want the user to call it shouldn't impact other algorithms interface. Algorithms in this context are ```volumeManager``` and ```mixerManager```.

Comment: You *say* that you don't want the "algorithms" exposed to the user, but the user has to pass an int constant that identifies them, and has to call different functions depending on the type he tells you to make.  Your requirements are very unnatural for an object-oriented language, and your library will seem very strange to C++ programmers.

Comment: @MattTimmermans understood. I think I am overcomplicating stuff.

Comment: @MattTimmermans If you do not know in advance (during compile time) what class shall be generated, then the abstract factory is the correct approach. Then you cannot call ````std::make_unique```` for the desired derived class during compile time. So I am not sure, if your statements fit all the needs. Unfortunately, you will write a long answer to me now and explain, why I am wrong and you are right. Before doing that please consider. There are millions of possible solutions and, with only seeing a small number of requirements here in the question, we cannot give an absolute answer.

Comment: @ArminMontigny agreed.

Comment: @user3053970 There is a general design principle that in this case says that if a user wants to invoke functionality specific to `MixerManager`, the user should have a pointer to `MixerManager`. Having merely a pointer to `TestAlgModule` is a warning flag that the design probably should be improved (not definite, but likely).

Comment: @JaMiT intention was this, suppose you have ```a, b, c``` and ```d```algorithms and they provide some common interfaces which you are able to encapsulate in a common class which you can be used by the user but now suddenly a new algorithm ```e``` comes which doesn't align to this standard interface(needs new function to initialize a new parameter or different function which does processing in a different way) so what would you do.

Comment: @user3053970 I would re-examine the designs involved. See if there were bad assumptions made in the design of the base class. See if `e` was not formulated well. Make sure the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping) is being followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an abstract factory, like you did in above code, then you need to return a pointer to the base class. That is correct. And then you need to invoke all functions through the base pointer.

By the way, please do not use raw pointers. Please use `std::unique` pointers instead.

There are 2 possible solutions.

Add the interface functions as a none pure, but still virtual function to your base class, with a default behaviour.

```
virtual void differentFunction() {}
```

Because of the other pure functions, the base class is still abstract. This may lead to a fat interface. But in many cases it is an acceptable solution.

The second possibility is to downcast the base class pointer to your needed pointer, using `dynamic_cast` and checking the return value of the dynamic cast.

```
if(mixerManager* mm = dynamic_cast<mixerManager*>(test)) {
    mm->differentFunction();
}
```

All this depends of course on the overall design and what you want to achieve. But the above 2 are the standard patterns.

There are also other design patterns that may fit your needs, like builder or prototype. Please check.